# получение данных о беседе (название беседы) (php vk api)

Tags: php, vkontakte-api

Либо я совсем глупый камешек,либо да.

```
$confInfo = $vk->request("messages.getChat",["chat_id" => $chat_id]);
$titleconf = $confInfo[0]['title'];
```

Пытаюсь получить название беседы путем запроса через методы вк.

В результате должно вывести название беседы:

```
$vk->sendMessage($log, "✅Из беседы: $peer_id Название: $titleconf был удален @id$kick_id($first_name $last_name)\nПо запросу $firstsecond_name $lastsecond_name\nПричина: $idc");
```

Теоретически все должно работать,а на самом деле не работает.

Админка у бота есть и с ней все хорошо.

Помогите(

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Решил сам проблему таким методом.

```
$chat_data = $vk->request('messages.getConversationsById', ['peer_ids' => $peer_id, 'extended' => 0]);
        $title = $chat_data['items'][0]['chat_settings']['title'];
        /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        $idc = implode("", $args);
        
        $vk->sendMessage($peer_id,"Увы, нам пора прощаться.");
        $vk->request('messages.removeChatUser', ['chat_id' => $chat_id, 'member_id' => $kick_id]);
        $vk->sendMessage($peer_id, "@id$kick_id ($first_name $last_name)\n✅Удален из беседы по запросу $firstsecond_name $lastsecond_name\nПричина: $idc ");
        $vk->sendMessage($log, "✅Из беседы: $peer_id Название: $title  был удален @id$kick_id($first_name $last_name)\nПо запросу $firstsecond_name $lastsecond_name\nПричина: $idc");
```

Comment: если нужен будет либ - скину

Answer (score 2):

Хз че там по либе и как Вы её используете, но на чистом, рукописном, все работает прекрасно.
Хранимая процедура:

```
var gAll = API.messages.getChat({
  'chat_id': 69
});

return gAll.title;
```

Аналог на PHP (на коленке +-). Скорее всего над поправить чутка.

```
   $code = urlencode('var a = API.messages.getChat(
    {
        "chat_id":"69"
    });
    return a;
    ');
    $query = file_get_contents("https://api.vk.com/method/execute?code=".$code."&v=5.103&access_token=".$token);
    $result = json_decode($query);
    $title = $result->response[0]->title;
```